FOSS alternative to GitHub Copilot?
Is there a FOSS (free, open source) alternative to GitHub Copilot, preferably one that can be integrated into Vim?

I think Tabby, "Opensource, self-hosted AI coding assistant", is what you're looking for:


Easy to configure: Controls deployment with simple TOML config
Open source: Audit the entire Tabby codebase for security or compliance on Github. Or host your own deployment.
Powered by Rust: Brings the best-in-class speed and safety of Rust, to make your coding experience as quick and reliable as possible.

It has integrations with the major editors and IDEs, including Vim/NeoVim.
The project was started by ex-Google engineers, is open source, written in Rust, and is compatible with several models with different licenses. You can learn more in their documentation.
You can find the source here: https://github.com/TabbyML/tabby.

This looks good and open: 17.7k ★s on GitHub (compared to 3.5k ★s for codium.vim).

Tabnine has a plugin for NeoVim, and unlike Microsoft Copilot, it puts a minimum level of effort into respecting copyright. The dataset it was trained on is listed at https://trust.tabnine.com.

While that's what they're advertising, it's not correct. Per their website: “The licenses are as follows: MIT, MIT-0, Apache-2.0, BSD-2-Clause, BSD-3-Clause, Unlicense, CC0-1.0, CC-BY-3.0, CC-BY-4.0, RSA-MD, 0BSD, WTFPL, ISC.” Many of these (e.g. MIT, Apache, BSD, CC BY) require attribution. If they'd only used CC0, 0BSD and WTFPL, it'd be fine, but they haven't.

@wizzwizz4 Their site contains a list of all repositories used in the dataset, so you can link to that list as attribution.

Not according to the text of the MIT license. “The above copyright notice and this permission notice shall be included in all copies or substantial portions of the Software.” (emphasis mine) The other licenses are similar.

They're definitely better at complying with terms than copilot, but still not good enough.

Legal questions aside, I doubt a reference like "maybe this project contains some snippets originating somewhere, in some form, from " maintains the spirit of OSS licensing. As much as companies want to wiggle around it, we are going to need new licensing that allows to explicitly opt in/out of ML training.

@xLeitix Have you looked at the transitive dependencies of a project of any appreciable size recently? We're well into "some snippets from " land manually.

@Caleth But given any particular snippet, it's the work of maybe three minutes to identify exactly which project it's from, who wrote it, and (in many cases) the historical context of its development.

@wizzwizz4 only if you have source access to application. If you've been handed a native .exe, or a website that's minified it's js, you don't have "any particular snippet" from which to look, but you can have a screen listing thousands of package names, as they were extracted from a package manager's state

https://www.continue.dev/ for VSCode and JetBrains
Can be used with self hosted LLMs with https://ollama.com/
(As for the preferable part) I don't think it has a vim integration as of this time.

Perhaps codegpt is worth a look.
It's not open source but there is a free tier. It is not for Vim either.
They have documented via Screenshot (and Video) how to configure VSCode to build a connection to one of several common "AI Providers". Then you choose one from that list of providers (which you need to be registered with). Then you can control a bit better where to send your prompts and your code snippets to.
I found CodeGPT/VSCode/PerplexityAI integration relatively simple to set up. Maybe this can be used as an intermediate learning-step, when going directly to self-hosted LLMs is too complicated.

This answer is not relevant at all - they explicitly want something open-source that works with vim.
